# @BeforeTest @AfterTest running only once

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am working on web whatsapp automation for practice using selenium-maven-cucumber-testng . I have below issue.

Expected: I have many feature files and I want to run all the feature files one after another as below :

take first feature file -> open browser ->run steps mentioned in feature file -> close browser. take second feature file -> open browser - > run steps mentioned in feature file -> close browser and so on.

Result :  Currently all the feature files are getting run and passing. But the browser is opening only once i.e.,

Open browser -> run feature file 1, feature file2, etc -> Close browser.

I want to run as explained in "Expected".

My Testng : 
[testng.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H5Kc.png)
[image: testing.xml]

My RunnerClass :

[Runner.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTKFc.png)
[image: Runner.java]

My Hook :

[Hook.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRcha.png)
[image: Hook.java]

Comment: Please post your code here, not link to an image - please edit your question using the Edit link.

Answer (score 0):

`BeforeTest` and `AfterTest` will run only once as there is only one `test` block in the testng.xml. One way would be to create separate runners for each feature file and have separate `test` blocks.

```
<test name="Feature_File_1">
    <classes>
      <class name="Runner1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Feature_File_2">
    <classes>
      <class name="Runner2"/>>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Also in the current runner class remove junit annotation `@RunWith`.

Comment: Sure I will do that. Also, in my entire code, I have not mentioned @ Test. Could you please let me know how it is running my code ? Only place where I can see @ Test is inside AbstractTestNGCucumberTests which is extended by my runner class.

Comment: Check out the code inside the AbstractTestNG...... class. Its pretty self explanatory. It has a dataprovider and other goodies. It does all the heavy work.

Comment: @Grasshopper : I don't think , it is a good practice if you have to use <test> for each test for this use case.

Comment: @cruisepandey What is the good practice that is being violated? Also the beforetest and aftertest config methods will not be run for 'each' test but only once for the <test> block in xml.

Comment: Grasshopper : in that case can't we go with @beforeMethod to launch the browser , as OP intended.He wants to launch the browser for every test method.

Comment: @cruisepandey Not exactly right, they want to open browser for all tests in a single feature file and then close the browser. A feature file may contain more than one test.

Comment: @Grasshopper : I might have got it wrong, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your TestNG hooks to Cucumber hooks.
Why is that? 
Cuz you want to close the browser after each scenario as you elaborated in your question.

Please see below:

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class Hooks {

@Before
public void beforeScenario(){
    System.out.println("This will run before the Scenario");
}   

@After
public void afterScenario(){
    System.out.println("This will run after the Scenario");
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry.. it is not even launching now if I make it as @ before